# mysql connection not getting resolved through hosts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am connecting to a MySQL database using PHP PDO like so:

```
$dbconnection = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;dbname=xxxxxx',
    $username,
    $password,
    array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
);
```

I have two servers, one for production and one for development. I changed hosts in development to resolve `xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com` to `xxxxxx-dev.xxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com` like so:

```
xxxxxx-dev.xxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com    xxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xx-xxxx-x.rds.amazonaws.com
```

I thought that this would connect to my development database instead of production on my development server. But this didn't happen, it still connects to production. Why is that?

Comment: how did you change hosts

Comment: Why dont you change to dev server in $dbconnection ???

Comment: Are you shure that your dev-host really points to your dev database server?